# How programmatically find correct smtp server address based only on email address domain?

Tags: delphi, smtp

I have a smtp scanner (brute force multithread program that tests each email account using a password list previous defined). The program is the : *Sanmao SMTP Mail Cracker*.

[Files of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKoWO.png)

One thing that called my attention in this program was the capacity of assign of smtp server address to each email.

All know that normally a smtp server address start with the words: mail or smtp followed of domain.

Examples:

- email: **myname@gmail.com** => smtp address: **smtp.gmail.com**
- email: **myname@bankrefah.ir** => smtp address: **mail.bankrefah.ir**

until this moment all fine.

But i saw a email with following domain: ***myname@hays.com.br*** and the program assigned ***eu-smtp-inbound-2.mimecast.com*** as smtp server address.

Now i wants know how is possible assign correctly ("discover") a smtp address to any email address (like was made in this program) programatically in Delphi.

Thank you.

**Update:**

After answer of @Remy Lebeau i have this code based in a [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650297/how-to-lookup-dns-records-with-indy-in-delphi).

```
function ResolveMx(email: string; dnsHost: string): string;
var
  DNS: TIdDNSResolver;
  I, J: Integer;
  sDomain: string;
  Record_: TResultRecord;
  Txt: TTextRecord;
  Srv: TSRVRecord;
  MX: TMXRecord;
begin
  DNS := TIdDNSResolver.Create(nil);
  try
    J := Pos('@', email);
    if (J > 0) then
      sDomain := Copy(email, Succ(J), Length(email))
    else
      sDomain := email;
    DNS.WaitingTime := 3000;
    DNS.QueryType := [qtTXT, qtService, qtMX];
    DNS.Host := dnsHost;

    try

      DNS.Resolve(sDomain);
    except
      on e: exception do
        Form1.mmo1.Lines.Add(e.message);
    end;

    for I := 0 to DNS.QueryResult.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Record_ := DNS.QueryResult[I];
      case Record_.RecType of
        qtTXT:
          begin
            Txt := TTextRecord(Record_);
            // use Txt.Text as needed...
          end;
        qtService:
          begin
            Srv := TSRVRecord(Record_);
            // use Srv.OriginalName, Srv.Service, Srv.Protocol, etc as needed...
          end;
        qtMX:
          begin
            MX := TMXRecord(Record_);
            Result := MX.ExchangeServer;
          end
      else
        // something else...
      end;
    end;
  finally
    DNS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But nothing is returned.

How solve?

**Update2:**

The code is working correctly after insert a well-known dns server (*8.8.8.8*, of Google) like suggested by @Remy Lebeau.

Comment: That's a MX DNS query.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, but all smtp servers address are of type **MX**?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, i found [this site](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3ahays.com.br&run=toolpage) where is possible find correct smtp server address based in some domain. How make it programatically in Delphi? some idea?

Comment: All mail is exchanged by mail exchangers. You can probably salvage the question if you modify it to ask about programmatic way of doing this.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform a DNS query to lookup a given domain's MX record.  That will tell you the address(es) of its SMTP server(s).

For instance, you can use Indy's `TIdDNSResolver` component for that purpose.

Comment: ok i found [this example](http://www.delphipraxis.net/665839-post11.html) but is generating several error of compilation. You have some example of code that can provide?

Comment: @Sormanne you did not say what version of Indy you are using, or what errors you are getting. That example code is actually internal code used by Indy's `TIdSMTPRelay` component. Please edit your question to show the actual code you are having trouble with in your own project, and what the errors are.

Comment: good observation this code is of Indy component, you is right :-). Then how return a string containg only correct smtp server address? seems that this procedure above, only fill a list with all results.

Comment: @Sormanne you keep saying you are getting errors, but you still haven't shown what the errors actually are. As for requiring a DNS host to send queries to, you can ask the OS for available DNS servers, if you don't want the caller to provide one.

Comment: code above returns the exception: (**DNS not responding**).

Comment: @Sormanne you are catching an exception, but you are not logging what the exception actually is. A DNS query could fail for any number of reasons.

Comment: the error is: **Code: 123.**
*Syntax for file name, directory name, or volume label is incorrect*. Parameters passed to function: *someuser@hotmail.com*, *hotmail.com*

Comment: @Sormanne that is not a DNS error code. What is the ACTUAL EXCEPTION that is being raised?

Comment: @Sormanne You changed your code to request `TXT` and `SRV` records and not `MX` records anymore. You need `MX` records to accomplish what you want. Only `MX` records carry the information you are looking for. I didnt ask you to change the code. I asked you to elaborate on the errors you were getting. You didn't do that.

Comment: even adding `qtMX` to `QueryTypes`, nothing comes.

Comment: Please, could edit your answer adding a functional example and usage?

Comment: then, why your code not works? are passed these parameter to the function: **user@yahoo.com**,  **yahoo.com**. Comes a generic error code: **123** that say: *The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.*. Why?

Comment: @Sormanne you already have the correct code to query `MX` records. You don't need `TXT` and `SVR` records, so stop requesting them. Error code 123 is NOT a DNS error. The error message text you quoted belongs to Windows error code 123, which is `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`. The only thing I can think of to cause that is if you are setting `TIdDNSResolver.Host` to an invalid DNS server. I suggest you use a well-known server for starters, like [Google's public DNS servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4)

Comment: @Sormanne Do you understand what DNS is? If not, I suggest you do some research. DNS is a lookup protocol primarily used to convert hostnames to IP addresses, amongst other uses. You can use any DNS server you want. Google's DNS servers are public, and have nothing to do with Gmail. Or, you can ask the user's OS for the DNS server used by the user's Internet connection. It is up to you. The end result is the same. Use *any* DNS server on the Internet to query MX records of your email domains.