# TIdTCPClient fails to resolve hostname multiple when not via primary DNS

Tags: delphi, indy

Using Delphi XE 10.2.3 and Indy 10.6.2.

I have an application in which I use a TIdTCPClient, on a customer project we expirence some troubles using DNS name of the remote server.
It appears as the TIdTCPClient only uses the default dns for the lookup, however at this customer the DNS server which "holds" the DNS name to resolve is on the third DNS on the network adapter.

When,
Using nslookup hostname(URL) it fails
Using nslookup hostname(URL) dnsserver it works

Pinging works whithout problem.

So I guess that nslookup also only uses the primary DNS server, and maybe uses the secondary DNS if the primary (and so fourth) DNS server is unavailable.

Is there some property in the TIdTCPClient I can set, to make it iterate and use all DNS specified on the server or do I need a different approach to resolve the hostname and connect the TIdTCPClient?
I really don't want to put the name in the "hosts" file.

Error from TIdTCPClient connect and status event.

07:22:50 LARGE: ivDispatch status:Resolving hostname interviewalarmreceiver.corp.novocorp.net

07:22:50 ERROR: SendLowLevelPackage(-310070) Socket Error # 11001
Host not found.

Comment: Note that DNS means "domain name **system**" (not "server"). Also note that Indy (in contrast to nslookup) only executes the API of the underlying OS, so it's most likely not a culprit. If it were Windows I'm not even aware of being able to assign more than a secondary DNS server. Try `TIdDNSResolver` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/39712620/4299358

Comment: True on the abbreviation - a third+ DNS can be added on a network adapter IPV4, under advanced setting, a tab DNS allows that.
The TidDNSResolver also need a specific DNS server, it won't iterrate DNS servers.

It's just wierd that the ping actually works since that must be iterrating configured DNS serveres.

Comment: Ping doesn't iterate configured DNS servers - that is not how DNS works. The first reachable DNS server will responds with NXDOMAIN if it can't resolve the name and DNS based resolution will stop there. The Windows ping command will try other methods of resolution like WINS / NetBIOS. See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/172218/